# How to JS function to catching Reload Button

Tags: javascript, button, reload

How can i write JS function to catching a Reload Button (on browser) then i pressed on.
I want to pop up alert something like that.

etc. -> and back button too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't.

The only solution is to use window.onbeforeunload to catch when user leaves page - reloads or uses back.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect these directly, you can use `onbeforeunload` to handle *any* unloading, including closing the browser, for example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Are you sure?"; };
```

But you can't detect what caused it, e.g. closing would as well, so would going forward in history.